# select info of students that got A on all their exams

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, group-by

I have three tables:

```
STUDENT
Studentid (pk) | Lastname | Firstname

SUBJECT
Subjectcode (pk) | Subjectyear (pk) | Subjectname

EXAM
Studentid (pk, fk) | Subjectcode (pk, fk) | Subjectyear(pk, fk) | Grade
```

I need to make a select statement that returns the Studentid, Lastname and Firstname of all the students that only got the grade A on their exams in their subjects.
So let's say that a particular student had exams in three different subjects and got A, B and A, then they shouldn't be included in the result.
If another student had two exams in two different subjects and got A and A, they must be included in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is aggregation:

```
select st.studendid, st.lastname, st.firstname
from student st
inner join exam ex on ex.studendid = st.studendid
group by st.studendid, st.lastname, st.firstname
having min(ex.grade) = max(ex.grade) and min(ex.grade) = 'A'
```

Actually, assuming that `'A'` is the least grade alphabetically-wise, the `having` clause can be simplified as:

```
having max(ex.grade) = 'A'
```

Note that you don't need the `subject` table to get the result that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all students have at least 1 exam, then you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select s.* from student s
where not exists (
  select 1 from exam
  where studentid = s.studentid and grade <> 'A'
)
```